# symfony 2 (sonata admin 2.2) validate emebed document

Tags: php, validation, symfony, sonata-admin, doctrine-odm

I want do validation embedded document (Doctrine ODM) in Sonata Admin Bundle version 2.2.
I tried following [documentation](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/reference/conditional_validation.rst#using-the-admin-class). But when i click the save button in ApplicationAdmin this method `validate` is not called.

Here is my sample code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/svolobuev/3e10215c9185af97750c/4f0dcca611b1efcb85673885101bbd8c68be88c8).

What can you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. See [gist](https://gist.github.com/svolobuev/3e10215c9185af97750c/a6c8ef818247d7902c6c0ea4cabd2f4d418fb2a9).
you need to add validator @Assert\Valid in your embedded document property, [see in the code](https://gist.github.com/svolobuev/3e10215c9185af97750c/a6c8ef818247d7902c6c0ea4cabd2f4d418fb2a9#file-mybundle-document-application-php-L43)